# I am using tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory() for multi-class classification to load images. How do i calculate confusion matrix?

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, tf.keras, confusion-matrix, image-classification

I am using tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory() for multi-class classification to load images. How do i calculate confusion matrix in this case as i load dataset in two parts validation part and training part in below format?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ja4k4.png)

There is no x_train,x_test in this type, so how to calculate confusion matrix in this case ?

please help in this case.

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly, 
which text allows for (and pictures do not).
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can create confusion matrix for the training and validation dataset which were imported using `image_dataset_from_directory()` after training the model.

For that you need to get the actual and predicted value along with the label_names of the dataset.

```
label_names = train_ds.class_names
y_true = tf.concat(list(val_ds.map(lambda s,lab: lab)), axis=0)
y_pred = model.predict(val_ds)
y_pred = y_pred.argmax(axis=1)
```

Now you can calculate and display the confusion matrix using below code:

```
import seaborn as sns 
confusion_mtx = tf.math.confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 4))
sns.heatmap(confusion_mtx,
            xticklabels=label_names,
            yticklabels=label_names,
            annot=True, fmt='g')
plt.xlabel('Prediction')
plt.ylabel('Label')
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]

Please check this replicated [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/RenuPatelGoogle/6c0fa60730f23d2b3ec288a46e3d811f/76450930.ipynb) for the reference.